# some one has difficulties "on", "in", or "with"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Which one of following expression is more clear, grammatical and idiomatic?

> He has difficulties **on** complex mathematical computation.
>
> He has difficulties **in** complex mathematical computation.
>
> He has difficulties **with** complex mathematical computation.

I prefer last one, but I am not sure and need double confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other languages it might be suitable to use **on** or **in**. In English, the correct way is:

> He has difficulties **with** complex mathematical computation.

Depending on the exact desired meaning, you may use:

> He has difficulties **doing** complex mathematical computation.

---

Additionally, you should use the plural: **computations**:

> He has difficulties **doing** complex mathematical computation**s**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll go with `He has difficulties with complex mathematical computation`. Should this one use computations?

Comment: Plural in all of them.

Comment: Plural is not needed if you consider the uncountable meaning, which I thinks makes more sense here (i.e. - the general act of computing things, rather than a set of particular computations)

Comment: Unless needed, communication needs (according to my exeprience) to be as specific as possible. This is why I preferred to take into account the countable form, rather the uncountable.